# Getting Error while trying to initiate Logic App Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]I am trying to configure a Logic App using Event Grid Trigger. The Trigger should be when my Azure CMK in my key vault is nearing expiry it should send me an email. I have configured the Logic App using the Logic App Designer, but when i try to run the trigger, it throws me the error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

The screenshot for my designer is also attached. Any idea what do i need to do to fix this[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Also putting the code here for reference.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>Your CMK will expire in 30 days</p>",
                        "ReplyTo": "myemailaddress ",
                        "Subject": "Key Expiry",
                        "To": "myemailaddress"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['outlook']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "filter": {
                                "includedEventTypes": [
                                    "Microsoft.KeyVault.KeyNearExpiry"
                                ]
                            },
                            "topic": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/pallabdev/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testhalvault"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('subscriptionId')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.KeyVault.vaults')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-06-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureeventgrid_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/PallabDev/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureeventgrid",
                    "connectionName": "azureeventgrid",
                    "connectionProperties": {
                        "authentication": {
                            "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                        }
                    },
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/canadacentral/managedApis/azureeventgrid"
                },
                "outlook": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/PallabDev/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/outlook",
                    "connectionName": "outlook",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/canadacentral/managedApis/outlook"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The trigger body is null. This looks like your using event grid which maybe worth tagging. Can you give us information on the eventgrid webhook setup?

Comment: What happens if you disable Split On?

Comment: May I ask if the error is caused by [manual triggering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQE8M.png).

Comment: @FrankGongWhen i click on Manual Trigger, it just sits there and doesn't do anything

Comment: @10pWell after i disabled Split On and manually triggered the Logic App, i got the email. So what was the issue you think, what does this Split On thing actually do?

Comment: @Pallab. The reason is that the `triggerbody` is `null`, it needs to be an `array`, if it is `null`, it will cause your error. `Null` may be triggered abnormally, so I ask you if it is triggered manually, it should be triggered automatically when the key is about to expire.

Comment: I see that `Split On` is turned on by default. If it is a test, have you created a key that is about to expire? There seems to be no problem with my test like this, please check how you triggered it.

Comment: @FrankGongYes i have created a key which is about to expire in one month, i am waiting to see if i get the email tomorrow or not. As i said , manual worked and i got success, waiting for the automatic thing to trigger now and see if i receive the email . Will update here

Comment: @Pallab. Maybe you can post an answer to help others who are suffering from this confusion.

Comment: @FrankGong I am not getting the automatic alert somehow. I only get the email when i  go to Overview and click on "Run Trigger" . Do i need to go to my Key Vault and create any Event there using the Event option from the left hand side? I didn't do anything on the KV side, whatever i have configured was only in the Logic App Designer.

Comment: At the moment i don't have any subscriptions on my Key Vault side as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the `triggerbody` is `null`, it needs to be an `array`, if it is `null`, it will cause your error.

According to the discussion in the comment area, turning off `Split On` can avoid this error.